# join in rails 4 with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Blog and Category models in my rails 4 application. there is a many to many relationship between these two models. i have multiple checkbox. I want to get all the blogs which belongs to that category. I have this in my Blog model

```
scope :by_categories, lambda{|category_ids| joins(:blog_categories).where("blog_categories.category_id in (?)", category_ids) if category_ids.present?}
```

and this in my controller

```
def search_blogs
 @blogs = Blog.by_categories(params[:category_ids])       
end
```

but whenever i choose multiple categories like category_ids => [1,2,3] , I am getting blogs for only category_id 1 and not for 2 and 3

Comment: Can you post the logs from the point where the request happens? Basically, I want to see the SQL getting generated.

Comment: SELECT `blogs`.* FROM `blogs` INNER JOIN `blog_categories` ON `blog_categories`.`blog_id` = `blogs`.`id` WHERE (blog_categories.category_id in ('1,3'))  ORDER BY published DESC

Comment: now here i want to get all the blogs which belongs to category_id 1 and 3 , but I am getting result for id 1 not for 3

Comment: @kali here problem is your params[:category_ids] is a string. Make them array of ids to get desired output

Comment: ('1,3'). This is string expected (1,3)

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are getting blogs having by categories. So use following code:

```
scope :by_categories, lambda{|category_ids| joins(:blog_categories).where("blogs.category_id in (?)", category_ids) if category_ids.present?}
```